# How to force a Qt Application to be the active/foreground window upon execution in OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, user-interface, window

I'm going through Qt tutorials on OSX. One thing I noticed is that when I launch the executable (e.g. the push button hello world example), the app will launch as a background window and I have to switch tasks to bring it into the foreground. How can I force the Qt application window to be the foreground window upon execution?

I'd like to do this since it's how most apps behave, not to mention that manually switching tasks slows down my edit-compile-run-debug cycle).

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you observe is due to interaction with the debugger when you start the application under the debugger using ⌘-Y. If you simply run it using ⌘-R, it behaves as you expect. Your application itself is fine.

Starting OS X applications by directly firing up the executable from within the app bundle from the terminal will act similarly to running them using ⌘-Y -- they all start in the background. Qt is probably mimicking whatever magic Finder does when it starts the process via ⌘-R -- said magic may reduce to simply bringing the child app to the foreground. gdb on OS X is not so "clever", and probably for a good reason.

OS X approach is to try harder not to steal focus -- a good thing IMHO.

If you merely want to *run* the application, not debug it, then modify your launch command to look like `open -a '/Users/daj/foo/bar/baz.app'`, where baz.app is the app bundle folder. Do not append a trailing slash.

If you can coax your debugger to follow through to child processes, then you can of course launch open itself under gdb, and it will work as expected -- with your child application on top.

Comment: I'm using emacs / gcc rather than XCode or QtCreator. However, it also behaves like this if I run the executable from a terminal as well.

Comment: Native OS X applications behave the same way if you start them from a terminal. Just tried on Cyberduck.

Comment: Any idea how I might force stealing focus in OSX (at least some of my apps do it)? Doesn't have to be done through Qt.Manual task switching is fine normally, but over many edit-compile-run-debug cycles starts to add up. I'd like to avoid switching development environments just for this...

Comment: You'd have to look in the Qt's innards, perhaps at how it fires off a process, because somehow ⌘-R gets it right. Perhaps that code is in Qt Creator proper -- I wouldn't know.

Comment: Note that switching dev environments wouldn't help you. If you run it under gdb, it won't start on top, period. The application can hoist itself on top itself, but you'd have to figure out how. ⌘-R doesn't start it via the debugger, and if that's all you want, then you may as well do it the same way under emacs, see edit.